# OrientDB - copy database to remote server error

Tags: load-balancing, distributed, orientdb

Sorry for asking question again, but I cannot get this to work.

Firstly, I start an OrientDB server on 204, 
Then I start an OrientDB server on my local machine, and create a database

```
orientdb> create database remote:localhost/mydemo root password local graph
create database remote:localhost/mydemo root password local graph
Creating database [remote:localhost/mydemo] using the storage type [local]...

Disconnecting from remote server [remote:localhost/ddemo]...OK

Disconnecting from the database [ddemo]...OK
Connecting to database [remote:localhost/mydemo] with user 'admin'...OK
Database created successfully.

Current database is: remote:localhost/mydemo
```

Then I tried to copy this database to remote server 204:

```
orientdb> copy database mydemo admin admin 192.168.222.204 local
orientdb> copy database mydemo admin admin 192.168.222.204 local
copy database mydemo admin admin 192.168.222.204 local
Copying database 'mydemo' to the server '192.168.222.204' via network streaming...

!ERROR: Connection is closed
```

Why I got this error?

I also tried with JAVA API, no exception, but after execution, the database is not exist on remote server.

```
    OServerAdmin admin = new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost/mydemo");
    admin.connect("root", "password");
    admin.copyDatabase("ddemo", "admin", "admin", "192.168.222.204", "local");
```

How can I copy it to remote server so I can continue with the clustering work?

When I want to copy a database to 204, the remote server 204 should start as a clustering node or as a single server?

Is there any document for all these operations? Any document for how to setup clutering servers about OrientDB?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. You tagged this as [tag:cluster-analysis] (a data mining subject, also known as "clustering"), but you probably meant [tag:load-balancing] or something like that. Be more specific when you talk about "clustering", and choose the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create data store type as local, but giving the url as remote:.
Steps to configure cluster/distributed network.
- create database in one node.
- copy the db folder to other node
- start orinetDB server as dserver.bat.
it will create cluster.